# FIlter the top 50 values from multiple colums in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I got an R dataframe with several hundred rows and a total of 6 columns. The first column is my row description, the second one a numeric variable and the columns 3 to 6 are my scientific measurements of my four different treatments (thus four different columns).

I would now like to get the highest 50 value across all rows of all four columns containing the numeric measurements with the corresponding first two columns attached.

So far I've tried:

```
mat.df <- slice_max(mat.df, mat.df[,c(3:6)], n=50, prop, with_ties = TRUE)
```

but this does not give my the highest 50 results from all four columns.

Any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Max

Comment: Hi welcome.  Could you please provide us with a snippet of your data with dput(head(mat.df, 10))?  Also could you say a little more about what you mean by "across all rows of all four columns" can they be summed? Do you want a concatenation of the 50 top of each of the 4 columns?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply:

structure(list(Genus = c("Burkholderiaceae;__", "Burkholderiaceae;D_5__Burkholderia-Caballeronia-Paraburkholderia"
), Intercept = c(6.32112124983383, 5.9669237476976), `Control-Aliette` = c(-0.0240728955950088, 
-0.130337009974892), `Control-Luna` = c(-0.0155891922433365, 
-0.0437075642068375), `Control-Movento` = c(0.0836892177687216, 
0.250147466860824), `Control-Serenade` = c(-0.0571368805313464, 
-0.0697262383246776)), row.names = c("Burkholderiaceae;__", "Burkholderiaceae;D_5__Burkholderia-Caballeronia-Paraburkholderia"
), class = "data.frame")

Comment: And from the four Control-x columns I'd like the top 50 highest values and their entire responding row. So they shouldnt be summed.

I hope that clears it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to generate some data like yours more rows and similar values.  Notice that `order_by` is actually a formula and you can adjust whether you want absolute values or something else

```r
library(dplyr)

mat.df %>% 
  slice_max(order_by = ControlAliette + ControlLuna + ControlMovento + ControlSerenade, 
            n = 50, 
            with_ties = FALSE)
#>    Genus Intercept ControlAliette ControlLuna ControlMovento ControlSerenade
#> 1      w  6.435287    0.056526489 -0.08267739    0.079620300      1.09842783
#> 2      c  6.079201    0.558397153 -0.16290829    0.554822034      0.11534424
#> 3      m  6.192000    0.241815318 -0.11150510    0.088925592      0.82798422
#> 4      x  5.392598    0.105206847  0.11572941    0.043688356      0.73782691
#> 5      s  6.446660    0.650486353 -0.02469053    0.191842753      0.17521118
#> 6      n  5.296171    0.366777627 -0.20989214    0.749322631      0.05003869
#> 7      q  5.282046   -0.218363044  0.13508214    0.720711704      0.26279334
#> 8      r  6.149206    0.581825377 -0.17562109   -0.090843851      0.58309241
#> 9      h  6.925687    0.417453587 -0.20572095    0.321314117      0.36169818
#> 10     m  5.691742    0.285472121 -0.05085905    0.137731401      0.51481684
#> 11     c  5.145111    0.002638383  0.28201133    0.049834715      0.54417127
#> 12     c  5.307666    0.073090636  0.06610125    0.426498084      0.30129010
#> 13     w  5.260718    0.048086123  0.07908467    0.358431527      0.35255379
#> 14     m  6.211825    0.180772350  0.44305053    0.445286789     -0.26957951
#> 15     x  5.227344    0.225538161  0.16067200    0.002541409      0.37038387
#> 16     u  5.723938   -0.332155838 -0.12333414    0.454581607      0.75518647
#> 17     t  5.152110   -0.282558292 -0.03498565    0.531423513      0.53623335
#> 18     a  6.526487    0.229463088  0.36144873    0.377937318     -0.23017497
#> 19     k  6.757341    0.516884599  0.49018540   -0.021555273     -0.25513704
#> 20     v  5.446486   -0.064045063  0.04287848    0.563663731      0.15906521
#> 21     o  5.070087    0.170030563  0.10599479    0.398073757      0.02670369
#> 22     t  5.586618   -0.162407261  0.30959608    0.784672641     -0.23755880
#> 23     w  6.184066    0.295550746  0.23812025   -0.117498910      0.26837228
#> 24     d  5.848479    0.033128367  0.12548966    0.114049621      0.38727744
#> 25     b  5.544807    0.007965195  0.00866282    0.335334827      0.28700183
#> 26     n  5.251765    0.444732965 -0.09725644   -0.387806585      0.67485325
#> 27     x  6.123222    0.158880473 -0.40684437   -0.110981338      0.99074654
#> 28     g  5.259382   -0.154187237  0.30824362   -0.365527503      0.84178062
#> 29     g  6.496157   -0.053255524  0.18689232    0.181498712      0.31483353
#> 30     q  6.770110   -0.162705871  0.03580742    0.513900306      0.24142638
#> 31     r  5.901752   -0.062622025 -0.05764049   -0.101135091      0.81935090
#> 32     d  6.549394    0.380371776  0.02137438   -0.131768823      0.29908691
#> 33     b  6.675606   -0.130378318 -0.07211543    0.397251508      0.37068326
#> 34     s  5.110820    0.229168985  0.24135752    0.049987817     -0.01836014
#> 35     j  5.944663    0.251562062 -0.09888048    0.237664053      0.10494435
#> 36     m  6.547734    0.112588977 -0.12150620   -0.149065617      0.64185923
#> 37     r  6.560016    0.010965496 -0.26502303    0.162376862      0.55101225
#> 38     h  5.922249    0.398995408  0.31074350   -0.164695748     -0.09995690
#> 39     t  6.708726   -0.081686217  0.32626594    0.487625193     -0.32319336
#> 40     e  6.483050    0.455495878 -0.15995120   -0.014532759      0.12664553
#> 41     q  6.945471    0.032406517  0.02001101    0.652315538     -0.29794823
#> 42     s  5.800246    0.081368176  0.44097023    0.359698727     -0.49149988
#> 43     h  6.186769   -0.127186068  0.10296196   -0.117877929      0.52542571
#> 44     t  5.799786    0.359494314  0.30821149    0.213104574     -0.50623447
#> 45     o  5.592515   -0.072610242 -0.09783531    0.496258542      0.04371708
#> 46     x  5.605788    0.095883060  0.18309971    0.247253420     -0.15940040
#> 47     l  5.124376   -0.082027992  0.29219376    0.245457652     -0.09446580
#> 48     x  5.993785    0.081067454 -0.31210067    0.180427362      0.40128945
#> 49     i  6.691422   -0.169410111  0.33240079   -0.238838985      0.41678546
#> 50     q  6.706284    0.460427014 -0.34032290   -0.285672344      0.50624378

mat.df %>% 
  slice_max(order_by = abs(ControlAliette) + abs(ControlLuna) + abs(ControlMovento) + abs(ControlSerenade), 
            n = 50, 
            with_ties = FALSE)
#>    Genus Intercept ControlAliette  ControlLuna ControlMovento ControlSerenade
#> 1      w  6.163855    -0.01602246 -0.139432692     1.11086916     -0.66393207
#> 2      z  6.344662    -0.56700045  0.132946953    -0.64180401      0.57921853
#> 3      v  6.388810    -0.77792884 -0.187690390    -0.26208884      0.64532993
#> 4      g  5.179393     0.12719675  0.488018448    -0.94983749      0.15642056
#> 5      d  5.475559    -0.10763699 -0.251141467    -0.32858552     -0.99127322
#> 6      g  5.259382    -0.15418724  0.308243618    -0.36552750      0.84178062
#> 7      x  6.123222     0.15888047 -0.406844369    -0.11098134      0.99074654
#> 8      u  5.723938    -0.33215584 -0.123334142     0.45458161      0.75518647
#> 9      v  6.623464    -0.51131603  0.201377070     0.30133355     -0.59963009
#> 10     n  5.251765     0.44473297 -0.097256441    -0.38780658      0.67485325
#> 11     q  6.706284     0.46042701 -0.340322896    -0.28567234      0.50624378
#> 12     p  6.111853    -0.27896210  0.104354182    -0.68234909     -0.52491266
#> 13     i  5.024287     0.01636362 -0.392316890     0.68981739     -0.40043887
#> 14     t  5.586618    -0.16240726  0.309596080     0.78467264     -0.23755880
#> 15     r  6.424762    -0.27752663  0.263024479     0.55815724     -0.37006130
#> 16     l  6.219644     0.47414209 -0.133076705    -0.16541590     -0.68872026
#> 17     p  5.256076    -0.30643889 -0.364943892    -0.39541292     -0.37877951
#> 18     r  6.149206     0.58182538 -0.175621089    -0.09084385      0.58309241
#> 19     f  6.971580     0.14013934  0.252297801    -0.67945341      0.35465739
#> 20     c  6.079201     0.55839715 -0.162908293     0.55482203      0.11534424
#> 21     t  5.799786     0.35949431  0.308211494     0.21310457     -0.50623447
#> 22     t  5.152110    -0.28255829 -0.034985649     0.53142351      0.53623335
#> 23     n  5.296171     0.36677763 -0.209892141     0.74932263      0.05003869
#> 24     s  5.800246     0.08136818  0.440970230     0.35969873     -0.49149988
#> 25     m  5.734308    -0.50240458 -0.294817028    -0.27977801     -0.29563500
#> 26     m  6.211825     0.18077235  0.443050531     0.44528679     -0.26957951
#> 27     q  5.282046    -0.21836304  0.135082142     0.72071170      0.26279334
#> 28     k  6.724188    -0.21118584  0.313290229    -0.20714810     -0.60087592
#> 29     a  5.937355     0.27092841  0.089738018    -0.37856526     -0.57958569
#> 30     w  6.435287     0.05652649 -0.082677388     0.07962030      1.09842783
#> 31     x  6.437799     0.63411108 -0.330220416    -0.06455209     -0.28624028
#> 32     h  6.925687     0.41745359 -0.205720947     0.32131412      0.36169818
#> 33     q  6.912286     0.27655245 -0.285097288     0.24735970     -0.48033045
#> 34     k  6.757341     0.51688460  0.490185399    -0.02155527     -0.25513704
#> 35     h  5.782539    -0.12631548 -0.053706678    -0.48881997     -0.61186837
#> 36     a  5.053820     0.21205072 -0.532491520     0.29227655      0.23504310
#> 37     m  6.192000     0.24181532 -0.111505098     0.08892559      0.82798422
#> 38     e  5.241864    -0.63895794 -0.244007611     0.24505811      0.13904614
#> 39     m  5.494797    -0.17277764 -0.002460733    -0.41205105     -0.66710689
#> 40     n  5.178992    -0.50196726 -0.123846277     0.38787254     -0.21968941
#> 41     m  6.469092    -0.47968618 -0.161308327    -0.54584551     -0.04310575
#> 42     t  6.708726    -0.08168622  0.326265943     0.48762519     -0.32319336
#> 43     r  6.076358     0.22051300 -0.293593812     0.22617724     -0.47817442
#> 44     a  6.526487     0.22946309  0.361448730     0.37793732     -0.23017497
#> 45     j  6.292186    -0.65160300  0.201960978    -0.07772339     -0.25767368
#> 46     j  5.818572     0.04629336 -0.108579717    -0.36723803      0.66664097
#> 47     k  5.048105    -0.33966657  0.246071452    -0.47745520     -0.11651867
#> 48     o  6.491382    -0.16081949  0.091642534     0.31591590     -0.59354074
#> 49     v  6.795716    -0.03606983  0.008426413     0.26267357     -0.85435700
#> 50     x  6.265645    -0.41563103  0.165907772    -0.50745799      0.07073063
```

Your data simulated

```r
set.seed(2020)
mat.df <- data.frame(
Genus = sample(letters, size = 200, replace = TRUE),
Intercept = runif(n = 200, min = 5, max = 7),
ControlAliette = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 0, sd = .25),
ControlLuna = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 0, sd = .2),
ControlMovento = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 0, sd = .3), 
ControlSerenade = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 0, sd = .4)
)
```

Comment: It worked! thanks alot!!!

One more question though: Would it be possible to get the highest 25 values and the lowest 25 values (using slice_min?) and put them in a new dataframe?

Again, highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Yes you can do it in three steps.  1.  Run the `slice_max` and put the results in a temporary df.  2.  Do the same for `slice_min` 3.  `rbind(temp1, temp2)`